# bitbucket pipeline : systemctl (systemd)

Tags: linux, systemd, bitbucket-pipelines, systemctl

I have looked around, and I am afraid it's not possible, but maybe someone has an idea or some kind of workaround:
**Is there any way to run services via systemctl on a bitbucket pipeline ?**

I have code that generates service files and runs them via systemctl. I want to automate some tests by running that code which specifically calls systemctl.

typically, is it possible to run, on a pipeline, smth like this code:

```
serviceCmd = "sudo systemctl start " + serviceName;
std::system(serviceCmd)
```

any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: what if there is "a way", why would you do that? Why not just run the service? Do you want to deploy your application or restart a production service on production server, or run an ad-hoc service for running your application specific unit tests? The "is there any way" is too broad for a question. Is this XY question? Why do you want to use systemctl at all in a pipeline?

Comment: I have code that generates service files and runs them via systemctl. I want to automate some tests by running that code which specifically calls systemctl.
you're right, I didn't add enough info. I'll add some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this for any future people who might ask themselves the same:

As it happens, on Ubuntu 20 and Ubuntu 22 (not on CentOS 7.9 noor Ubuntu 18 though), you can simply install systemctl via

```
sudo apt-get install systemctl -y
```

And any usage of systemctl seems to be working.
I had to add a little hack though because I kept having an error message stating

```
ERROR:systemctl: man-db.service: Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: +/usr/bin/install -d -o man -g man -m 0755 /var/cache/man
```

To fix this, I did this in my DockerFile

```
[ -f /lib/systemd/system/man-db.service ] && sed -i 's/^\(ExecStart=+\)/ExecStart=/' /lib/systemd/system/man-db.service
```

so basically remove the + sign in the `man-db.service` file